# Appcelerator - Notify parent view if something happen on child view

Tags: view, parameters, parameter-passing, parent-child, appcelerator

How should I get info about child view's events on parent view?

For example:

I pass and argument to the child (Alloy.createController('myChildView', { info: test }).getView()). Then I work with it and set a global variable from false to true (Alloy.Globals.childPrecessed = true). After that, I can spent any time on this view, but when I click on a button which fires a hide event, I should process the info from parent view.

My first thought was I fire az appwide event (myChildHide), and listen for it in the parent view. If I catch it, then I process the info, and destroy the listener...

Is this the best method? I'm not sure...

Has anybody better solution for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a fan of event listeners, so I think your approach is a good one.

What I normally do is to initiate the event listener right before I need it to be effective, i.e. in the method opening the child window. But first I use backbone events for simple event triggering. See [Fokke Zandbergen's article for further info](http://www.tidev.io/2014/09/10/the-case-against-ti-app-fireevent-2/). So assuming you have set up a "dispatcher" then I would do something like this:

```
function openChild(){
   dispatcher.on("child-calling", doChildsWork);
   // ... open child view
}
```

Then in the `doChildsWork` I would disable the event handler once called:

```
function doChildsWork(args){
   dispatcher.off("child-calling");
   // ... do work initiated by child view using args...
}
```

And finally in the child view (assuming you have set up a "dispatcher") you would do something like this:

```
function doChildsWork(){
   // ... Tell parent to do some work
   dispatcher.trigger("child-calling",{test:true});
   // ... continue whatever is going on in child
}
```

I use this approach a lot - and it works well :-)

/John

Comment: Vote up for Fokke's article. I would use either callback or controller.on/controller.trigger.

Comment: Very detailed answer, great article, thank you, John! :)